# Parsing file-like object into create_ffmpeg_player in discord.py not working

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord.py

The API documentation for create_ffmpeg_player says it allows passing file-like objects into create_ffmpeg_player as it will be passed to stdin.

> ```
> create_ffmpeg_player(filename, *, use_avconv=False, pipe=False, stderr=None, options=None, before_options=None, headers=None, after=None)
> ```
>
> filename – The filename that ffmpeg will take and convert to PCM bytes. If pipe is True then this is a file-like object that is passed to the stdin of ffmpeg

here's what I am inputting:

```
buffer = BytesIO()
c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, buffer)
c.perform()
player = voice.create_ffmpeg_player(buffer,pipe=True)
```

The PycURL object writes data to `buffer` which is the BytesIO object.

Then I try to parse the file-like object into create_ffmpeg_player() but I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "test.py", line 116, in on_message
    player = voice.create_ffmpeg_player(buffer,pipe=True)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\voice_client.py", line 431, in create_ffmpeg_player
    p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdin=stdin, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=stderr)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 667, in __init__
    errread, errwrite) = self._get_handles(stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 904, in _get_handles
    p2cread = msvcrt.get_osfhandle(stdin.fileno())
io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno
```

The error shows me that somewhere in the stack, a routine is trying to get the fileno() of the object, but since this is not a real file, there is no file handle, or "fileno". For a temporary work-around I am creating a physical file on disk and parsing that file into the function, but for this program, the function will be run many times so doing physical read/writes is not practical. Is it possible to work around this, or at least create a file on memory with the ability to get/spoof a fileno?

Comment: How are you running your bot?

Comment: through windows powershell

Comment: I can't think of a way around this.  Closest would be to use temporary files from  [`tempfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html).  Usually you would pass `PIPE` to `Popen` and then use `communicate` to send the data to the subprocess.  Maybe you could try passing `PIPE` and then doing `player.process.communicate(DATA FROM buffer)`, but I wouldn't expect that to work.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Could I possibly mount a ramdisk to windows and perform my read/writes on that ramdisk? That would take the unnecessary burden/time off the hard disk